# How to assign a reference type to value type (create copy at value type)

Tags: c#

I have a class, below:

```
public Person(string name, int age)
{
    Name = name;
    Age = age;
}
```

After the class is declared, I have the following:

```
String OtherName;
Int OtherAge;
Person jane = new Person("Jane", 28);
OtherName = Jane.Name;
OtherAge = Jane.Age;
```

How do I store `OtherName` and `OtherAge` in such a way that they do not change when I change the value of `jane`?

Comment: can I be clear? you want `OtherName` and `OtherAge` to update when `jane.Name` and `jane.Age` are changed? That's probably not going to happen. This sounds like an X/Y problem. What are you trying to *achieve*? if you tell us what you're trying to do (rather than how), we can probably offer guidance. Side note: of those two (`Name` and `Age`), only one of them is a value-type.

Comment: Voting to close this question. Its not clear what the OP is asking.

Comment: Hello every one, I mean this: I want store a fixed value to `OtherName` (by `jane.Name`) for later use. My problem occur when I update jane.Name, OtherName update too.

Answer (score 3):

The variables `OtherName` and `OtherAge`, as it stands, are going to keep their values, even if the value of `jane`, or its properties, are updated.

Comment: @Aleksandar Please don't rush through your review queue. Take time and look at each post in it's context. This properly answers the question asked and should NOT have been a comment

Comment: @srsedate you could point out the difference between pass by value and pass by reference. That would improve your post by a lot

Comment: Hello every one, I mean this: I want store a fixed value to `OtherName` (by `jane.Name`) for later use. My problem occur when I update jane.Name, OtherName update too.

Comment: @LonelyNeuron you are right, this one is in the grey zone. The answer did explain the issue, but did not show the solution. Maybe a comment with that would be enough.

Comment: @Mr.Henry please update your question using the edit button

Comment: @Aleksandar it does provide a solution. The solution is, that it is already fixed

Answer (score -2):

I refactor Person class in the following, If name changes, other name will change. But Other name could change not to effect name prop.

```
public class Person
    {
        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { otherName = name = value; }
        }


        private int age;

        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { otherAge = age = value; }
        }

        private string otherName;

        public string OtherName
        {
            get { return otherName; }
            set { otherName = value; }
        }
        private int otherAge;

        public int OtherAge
        {
            get { return otherAge; }
            set { otherAge = value; }
        }


    }
```

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person jane = new Person("Jane", 28);
            jane.OtherName = jane.Name;
            jane.OtherAge = jane.Age;


            jane.Name = "Dave";
            jane.Age = 30;

            Console.WriteLine(jane.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(jane.Age);
            Console.WriteLine(jane.OtherName);
            Console.WriteLine(jane.OtherAge);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Output: 
Dave
30
Dave
30

Comment: I'm not sure from where you got the idea that `Person` had a `OtherName` and `OtherAge` property, but this is also the opposite of what the OP asked for

Comment: Yes , firstly I thought same with you @CamiloTerevinto, but I read in comments:"can I be clear? you want OtherName and OtherAge to update when jane.Name and jane.Age are changed? That's probably not going to happen. This sounds like an X/Y problem. What are you trying to achieve? if you tell us what you're trying to do (rather than how), we can probably offer guidance. Side note: of those two (Name and Age), only one of them is a value-type. – Marc Gravell". I think It should this question. If its not this. He would not to do anythink.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto to be fair, from its original (non-edited) state it is really hard to know what OP asked about

Comment: @LonelyNeuron unclear questions shouldn't be answered. If the OP doesn't clarify, the question should be closed. I am completely sure that `OtherName` and `OtherAge` shouldn't be properties from `Person` though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto if a question is unclear or not is often subjective. Maybe Basar Kaya was sure he understood the question. And I am not arguing with `OtherName` or `OtherAge`

Comment: Hello every one, I mean this: I want store a fixed value to `OtherName` (by `jane.Name`) for later use. My problem occur when I update jane.Name, OtherName update too.

Comment: hello @Mr.Henry I am sad for my response would not useful. And I gave -2 unuseful flag.  What you want to know in your question, because of your code is suitable to your aim.